# blender: 3D model from guide images

Tags: models, blender

In a effort to learn the blender interface, which is confusing to say the least, I've chosen to model a [model](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=elly+tran+ha) from referrence pictures easily found on the web.

Problem is that I can't ( and won't ) get perfect "right", "front" and "top" pictures. Blender only allows you to see the background pictures when in ortographic mode and only from right|front|top, which doesn't help me.

How to I proceed to model from non-perfect guide images?

Comment: That is where your artistic eye comes into play. You'll need to make the transformation in your mind's eye and then model that.

Comment: Start with a reference photo which does have near perfect front/side views. Got to learn the basics first before jumping into the details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first (successful) Blender modeling-from-reference-images experience came from the fantastically useful [Blender Noob-to-Pro wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Main_Page).  The [fox modeling exercise](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D%3a_Noob_to_Pro/Modeling_a_Fox_from_Guide_Images) not only supplies the images for you, but gave me some ideas about how I could combine household items and my phone's camera to produce my own reference images - since I'm not patient enough right now to learn how to sketch my own...

Honestly, going through most of that wiki got me to the point where I was able to make sense of almost all of the other tutorials I could find Googling.

Comment: i still have the entire noob-to-pro wiki printed and bindered

Answer (score 2):

You can also get left, back, bottom views. Try holding shift when using the keypad to activate those views. I would also suggest editing the images in photoshop or something similar first.

The blender noob to pro wiki is a bit out of date. Its not using the most recent Blender version (2.55) and as the interface is completely different, this could be confusing.

Try going to http://www.blenderatists.org/forum or irc freenode #blender for help